# Wordpress and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins

I have never messed with wordpress much and am real stuck. I am trying to add a video playlist/gallery via jquery.  Not a wordpress plugin.  I am not even sure what I am doing wrong and am hoping someone could help me through it please.  The site is here, http://okaysewwhat.com/  it is just a skeleton now since this does not work yet.
The jquery plugin I am using is this, http://www.geckonewmedia.com/blog/2009/8/14/jquery-youtube-playlist-plugin---youtubeplaylist

Ok so I have inside the header.php of wordpress, added this to call the stylesheet for the youtube part,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?phpbloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>/youtube.css" />
```

then after that is this part, you can see what I added,

```
    <?php


        wp_enqueue_script("jquery");

        if ( is_singular() ) wp_enqueue_script( 'comment-reply' );



        wp_head(); 

        global $options;
        foreach ($options as $value) {
             if (get_settings( $value['id'] ) === FALSE) { $$value['id'] = $value['std']; } else { $$value['id'] = get_settings( $value['id'] ); }
        }
    ?>

<script src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/jquery.youtubeplaylist.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>


<script type="text/ecmascript">
jQuery.noConflict();

    $(function() {
        $("ul.demo2").ytplaylist({addThumbs:true, autoPlay: false, holderId: 'ytvideo2'});
    });

</script>
```

Inside index.php I added, right under the wordpress main_col div,

```
<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/tube.php'); ?>
```

and all that is in tube.php is the list of vids,

```
<code>
    <div class="yt_holder">
    <div id="ytvideo2"></div>
    <ul class="demo2">
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBBWKvY-VDc">Video 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZXMQqLnRhRI">Video 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wvo-g_JvURI">Video 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</code>
```

I hope this is not too convoluded, I aploogize, I am just so lost in this I do not understand it anymore.  All that displays is a list like you would get from the ul above.
And firebug gives me the error

```
Firebug's log limit has been reached. %S entries not shown.     Preferences  
$ is not a function
okaysewwhat.com()okaysewwhat.com (line 40)
[Break on this error] $(function() {\n
```

which I dont get either.  I would appreciate any tips guys, thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery.noConflict

> By using this function, you will only be able to access jQuery using the 'jQuery' variable. For example, where you used to do $("div p"), you now must do jQuery("div p").

Comment: I had similar problem with Wordpress and jQuery, and this was the fix for me. Hope this works for you, thatryan.

Comment: This has nothing to do with WordPress though. If you're gonna use jQuery.noConflict(); and you'd still like to use something other thatn jQuery.whaterver, just do
`var jQ = jQuery.noConflict();` then you can do stuff like `jQ('div').blah blah`

Comment: but i change the script function to 
<code>
    <script type="text/ecmascript">
 jQuery.noConflict();

  jQuery(function() {
   jQuery("ul.demo2").ytplaylist({addThumbs:true, autoPlay: false, holderId: 'ytvideo2'});
  });
 
</script>
</code>
and still nothing, same error....?