# jQuery on Wordpress Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, wordpress

I am tackling on this code here on WordPress. Don't know how to get around it.

So, I have a four file input that are on a Wordpress theme. This form is to edit an ad and is filled with information retrieved form the database. If there is a picture, the input is hidden and appear a textfield and a button.

What I am trying to do is, to click the button and hide/remove the text field and button. And, after it make the file input appear.

This is how I am trying ro implement it:

```
                          <script language="text/javascript">
                        $(function(){
                            $('#btn1').click(function(){
                                        $.ajax({
                                            url:"/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                                            type:'POST',
                                            data:'action=my_special_action',
                                            success:function(results)
                                            {
                                                //  alert(results);
                                                $("#pic1").attr('type','file');
                                            }
                                        });
                                    }
                            );
                        });

                  </script>
              <?php for ($i=1;$i<=get_option('wpClassifieds_max_img_num','4');$i++):
                        if($i <= $num_rows) {
                            $ad_photos = mysql_fetch_array($res);
                            $upload_array = wp_upload_dir();
                            $upload_array['subdir'] = "awpcp"; ?>
                              <div class="pictures">
                                <label><?php _e('Picture', "wpct");?> <?php echo $i?></label>
                                <textarea id="text<?php echo $i; ?>" name="text<?php echo $i; ?>" readonly><?php echo $ad_photos["image_name"];?></textarea>
                                <button id="btn<?php echo $i?>" name="btn<?php echo $i?>" />remove
                                <input type="hidden" name="pic<?php echo $i?>" id="pic<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $_POST["pic".$i];?>" />
                              </div>
                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                    <div class="pictures">
                                        <label><?php _e('Picture', "wpct");?> <?php echo $i?></label>
                                        <input type="file" name="pic<?php echo $i?>" id="pic<?php echo $i?>" value="<?php echo $_POST["pic".$i];?>" />
                                    </div>
                              <?php } endfor; ?>
```

Can you help me please?

Thanks

Comment: So what isn't working?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/1456202/1270996

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all of your jQuery code in Wordpress like this:

Replace `$(function(){` with `jQuery(function ($) {`

Basically, Wordpress has setup jQuery in a way that won't conflict with other libraries that want access to the '$' character.

Comment: Thanks Nicholas. I've done it. However it does not work...

I would like to get AJAX working on this function but it just loads the entire page...

Comment: Why are you posting to `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`?

Comment: That's what I got when googling for AJAX and WordPess.
How should it be? How do I check errors?

Comment: Your browser should be able to show you javascript errors: https://www.google.com/#hl=en&sugexp=les%3B&gs_rn=4&gs_ri=psy-ab&tok=EAfWWlRDVMrPqn1ucQreOw&cp=22&gs_id=h9&xhr=t&q=view+javascript+errors&es_nrs=true&pf=p&safe=off&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=view+javascript+errors&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42661473,d.eWU&fp=ba1a9d90d6b31be2&biw=1600&bih=741

Comment: User2083008: Why are you using ajax?

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use `$('#btn1')` because then the script will only work on the button with ID `#btn1`.

Do something like this:

```
jQuery('.pictures button').on('click', function() {
  // If you need button ID
  var button_id = jQuery(this).attr('id');

  // Hide the text area
  jQuery(this).prev('textarea').hide(); 
  // And button
  jQuery(this).hide();
  // Show Input field
  jQuery(this).next('input').show(); 

});
```

I've not added `ajax`since I don't know the purpose of this.

Comment: Thanks Steven.
The problem is that the page automatically fully reloads. I would like to make this work without having to reload the page...
That's why I was trying to use AJAX.

Comment: It might be handled as submit. Try setting the `type="button"`. And drop the `.ajax` when testing this.

Comment: Yes, but this is only part of the form.